# How to include dotfuscated dll file to my c#.net project?

Tags: c#, .net

I have successfully dotfuscated my .dll file to prevent it from being easily read when decompiled...But the problem is, I can't use the dotfuscated dll file because my project can't seem to understand the contents of the file... Could anyone help me please?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the obfuscator on the final output (all of the projects together) so that it can handle references across assemblies.

Comment: @chad: Tell it to preserve public member names.

Answer (score 1):

Until that particular dll is obfuscated with option to be used as external library, you cannot reference it within your project.

Few obfuscator, obfuscate all the public classes & methods, hence referencing them is not useful.